# Activity still recreated with configChanges

Tags: android

As I understand it, if you insert 'android:configChanges="orientation"' into the activity in the manifest, the activity will not be destroyed and recreated on an orientation change. To test this, I created a dead-simple app which does NOTHING. Then I inserted 'android:configChanges="orientation"' in the manifest. Then I added the following method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.v(TAG,"onConfigurationChanged:");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

However, I'm still seeing onCreate() being called. The activity is still being recreated.

As if that weren't strange enough, I don't see onConfigurationChanged() being called when I put the emulator into landscape mode (Ctrl-F11). It's only called when I go back to portrait mode. Shouldn't it be called both ways? Isn't the configuration (orientation) being changed when I go into landscape as well as portrait modes? This makes no sense.

Anyway, this whole activity and orientation thing is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I'm still seeing onCreate() being called. The activity is still being recreated.

The emulator emulates a device with a side-slider keyboard. The `android:configChanges` value that matches your - would be `keyboardHidden`, generally used in conjunction with `orientation` to handle non-keyboard devices (e.g., `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`).

That being said, `android:configChanges` is not recommended in most cases. Use dynamic fragments and `setRetainInstance(true)`, or use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to allow the activity to be destroyed and recreated.

Answer (score 2):

Your screen size changes from 1200x800 to 800x1200 (for instance).

Since API 13, this will also raise a `screenSize` config change. The fix is:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```